# plt.subplot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
def plot_it(U1, U2, x, i):
    fig_1, = plt.plot(x, U1)
    fig_2, = plt.plot(x, U2)
    i = str(int(i/2 + 1)) if i != 0 else ''
    plt.xlabel('x, t =' + i + 'Δt')
    plt.ylabel('U')
    plt.legend(handles=[fig_1, fig_2], labels=['μ = 1', 'μ = 2'])
    plt.show()

plt.figure()
for i in range(11):
    U1[1:20] = np.linalg.solve(A1, B1.dot(U1[1:20]))
    U2[1:20] = np.linalg.solve(A2, B2.dot(U2[1:20]))
    if i % 2 == 0:
        plt.subplot(2, 3, int(i/2 + 1))
        plot_it(U1, U2, x, i)
```

I want the result is 2 rows 3 columns, but in fact it gives me 6 rows 1 column,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have your x, A1, A2 etc, so I am just showing how to use subplots -

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)

def plot_it(U1, U2, x, i, ax):
    ax.plot(x, U1)
    ax.plot(x, U2)
    i = str(int(i/2 + 1)) if i != 0 else ''
    fig_1 = ax.set_xlabel('x, t =' + i + 'dt')
    fig_2 = ax.set_ylabel('U')
    ax.legend(handles=[fig_1, fig_2], labels=['Test'])

plt.figure()
for i in range(11):
    U1 = [2,4,6,9,2,1, 2]
    U2 = [7, 9, 12, 78, 2, 12, 12]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        plot_it(U1, U2, x, i, axes[(i%4)/2, i/4])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I need, but I have two little changes,        "fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(18, 12)) ", "plot_it(U1, U2, x, i, axes[i//6, (2 * i) % 3])",